# How to read images in R to use them for a pre-trained model like VGG16?

Tags: r, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a folder `emotions`. In there is a folder `work` with 3 folders `train`, `test` and `val`.

Each of them has 7 folders with different emotions and each of these folders contains `PNG` images.

I want to read those images and use them to train a VGG16.

So far my code looks like this:

1. Read Images

```
library(tensorflow)
library(keras)
library(png)
library(magick)

read_img <- function(file) {
  img <- image_read(file)
  img_resized <- image_resize(img, "48x48!")    
  img_vec <- as.vector(as.matrix(image_data(img_resized)))
}
```

`img` is of type `externalptr` and when I print `img` the image is shown correctly

2. Read emotions dataset

```
library(abind)

# Function to read the emotions dataset
read_emotions_dataset <- function(directory) {
  emotions <- c("anger", "contempt", "disgust", "fear", "happy", "sadness", "surprise")
  image_files <- list()
  labels <- c()
  for (emotion in emotions) {
    emotion_dir <- file.path(directory, emotion)
    emotion_files <- list.files(path = emotion_dir, full.names = TRUE)
    image_files <- c(image_files, emotion_files)
    labels <- c(labels, rep(emotion, length(emotion_files)))
  }
  images <- lapply(image_files, read_img)
  images <- abind(images)
  list(images = images, labels = labels, image_files = image_files)
}
```

3. Make Train, Test and Val

```
# Read the train, test and validation datasets
emotions_train <- read_emotions_dataset("../data/emotions/work/train")
emotions_test <- read_emotions_dataset("../data/emotions/work/test")
emotions_val <- read_emotions_dataset("../data/emotions/work/validation")

# Split the images and labels into separate variables
emotions_train_images <- emotions_train$images
emotions_train_labels <- emotions_train$labels
emotions_test_images <- emotions_test$images
emotions_test_labels <- emotions_test$labels
emotions_val_images <- emotions_val$images
emotions_val_labels <- emotions_val$labels
```

I think there is a problem already with the shape.
When I do `dim(emotions_train_images)` I get `1352448` which I think is not correct.
Because I later get errors like `ValueError: Unsupported image shape` and so on.

//Edit:
The structure of the datasets is not correct. It looks like this:

```
images  labels
<raw>   <chr>
18  anger
0a  anger
0d  anger
10  anger
⋮   ⋮
9f  surprise
d7  surprise
```

So, I tried to reshape it like that

```
emotions_train_images_reshaped <- array(emotions_train_images, c(nrow(emotions_train_images), 48, 48, 1))
emotions_test_images_reshaped <- array(emotions_test_images, c(nrow(emotions_test_images), 48, 48, 1))
emotions_val_images_reshaped <- array(emotions_val_images, c(nrow(emotions_val_images), 48, 48, 1))
```

But not sure if this is correct?
Especially with the labeling.
And the dim is like 1352448 48 48 1

Here is my modelling part

```
# Load the VGG16 model with pre-trained weights
vgg16 <- application_vgg16(weights = "imagenet", include_top = FALSE, input_shape = c(48, 48, 3))

# Freeze the layers of the model to prevent them from being updated during training
for (layer in vgg16$layers) layer$trainable <- FALSE

# Add new layers on top of the VGG16 model for fine-tuning
x <- layer_flatten(vgg16$output)
x <- layer_dense(x, 128, activation = "relu")
x <- layer_dropout(x, 0.5)
predictions <- layer_dense(x, 7, activation = "softmax")

# Create a new model using the VGG16 model and the new layers for fine-tuning
model <- keras_model(inputs = vgg16$input, outputs = predictions)

# Compile the model with a categorical cross-entropy loss function and the Adam optimizer
model %>% compile(
  optimizer = optimizer_adam(),
  loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
  metrics = c("accuracy")
)

# Preprocess the images by converting them to arrays and normalizing the pixel values
emotions_train_images_array <- abind(lapply(emotions_train_images_reshaped, image_to_array))/255
emotions_val_images_array <- abind(lapply(emotions_val_images_reshaped, image_to_array))/255

# Train the model on the emotions dataset
history <- model %>% fit(
  x = emotions_train_images_array,
  y = emotions_train_labels,
  epochs = 10,
  batch_size = 128,
  validation_data = list(emotions_val_images_array, emotions_val_labels)
)
```

Comment: After the step `emotions_train <- read_emotions_dataset("../data/emotions/work/train")` can you explore the structure of `emotions_train` - is it as you expect?

Comment: Ah yeah.. the structure of the datasets is not what I expect.. I edited my post and added the output. Probably doing something wrong in the read image part??

Comment: Try running your `read_image()` on a single image and see if it gives you the expected output.  Similarly, test `read_emotions_dataset()` on a single folder.  If both of those work ok, then it's the loop and summary that needs investigating.

Comment: the output of 1 `img_vec` from my `read_image()` looks like this `[1] 18 0a 0d 10 08 0c 11 16 1d 18 0d 02 00 00 01 01 09 16 26 3b 50 5d 68 70` . Continues until [2281]. Not sure if this is correct though. I have just 80 photos in 1 folder but the `dim` of `emotions_train$images` is 186624..

Comment: Without the data to test it, I suspect `abind` is not doing what you want, and may actually be unnecessary.  The results of the `lapply()` should be a list with one element per image file already.  If you remove/comment out the `abind` line and re-run, do you get something closer to your expectation?